# Running a Java application insider a google sheet

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I wrote a Java application that works basically like a class scheduler that makes sure students aren't scheduled for more than one class at once and are taking all the classes they signed up for while trying to keep an even distribution of students in classes. The input data will be stored in a google sheet, and the functionality will be used by people who are not familiar with cs at all. I was wondering if there is a way to create a simple button in a google sheet that would call the main function in my java application, which could read the data in the spreadsheet and print a simple schedule table in the same spreadsheet.

I've seen examples where I could use the google API to access the sheet and then run my jar file locally. But I would like to use the least amount of steps possible, and preferably only require users to press a button that makes the schedule for them.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does your java run on the cloud and has a api that can be accessed with Google apps script/JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Not in a simple way, no. Google Sheets is running on the Google Cloud and can only access resources through a Web interface. So the easiest way for you to control your app via Google Sheets is to write a Web interface for your app, host it on a server accessible to anyone, and write some JavaScript in your Sheet that calls the Web API of your app.